# Why SQL query only works when running from VS but not outside

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012

I have a search textbox and a submit button, where the user can enter a name and hit the button to get a result. Only issue I am running into is when I run the website from VS, the query returns a result but when I make the website in to a web service
and access it using the link outside of the localhost link, it doesn't work (displays `Failed: Not not found in Database`).

My `localhost` link which works with search query: `http://localhost:53647/PDFFormsNew/searchcreate.aspx` (running through VS)

My IIS link which I am accessing outside of VS which doesn't work for the search query: `http://devserver-svr-dev:85/searchcreate.aspx`

Any idea why it is causing it and how to fix it?

I am including snippets of code which is doing the query:

```
string cString = "Data Source=svr-db;Initial Catalog=test-db;User Id=myusr;Password=p@$$w0rd;";
protected void btnValidateName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.sqlQuery();
}
public void sqlQuery()
{
    tc.Text = "HERE";
    Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
    Conn.Open();

    //nameE = '%'+txtName.Text+'%';
    nameE = '%' + RemoveSpecialCharacters(txtName.Text) + '%';
    sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [test-db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] LIKE @name"; //allow user to enter partial

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
    {
        //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameE);

        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                rptContent.DataSource = reader;
                rptContent.DataBind();
                lblIsValid.Text = "Success: Name found in Database";
                lblIsValid.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#009900");
                //btnGeneratePDF.Visible = true;
            }
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                rptContent.DataSource = null;
                rptContent.DataSourceID = null;
                rptContent.DataBind();
                lblIsValid.Text = "Failed: Name not found in Database";
                lblIsValid.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#990000");
                //btnGeneratePDF.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Conn.Close();
}

public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.')
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For sure the reason is described in error message.

Comment: Are you running your website from VS using VS Development Server or a Local IIS Server ?

Comment: _it doesn't work_ not very useful. Do you have an error message? If yes, add it to your question, if no, are you removing the exceptions with empty catch blocks?

Comment: `it doesn't work` means when I enter some text in the box and hit enter (and now pressing the button), the page just  displays `Failed: Name not found in Database`

Comment: @Vash-DamianLeszczyński Unfortunately there is no error message but let me test something out.

Comment: Not sure, but try to use the exact parameter name when you add the value to the Parameters collection "@name".

Comment: Follow @Steve's advice. And also, double check your connection string.

Comment: I added the entire code for the button click even to my question for a better look.

Comment: That is weird... I change the code to this: `sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [test-db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] LIKE '" + nameE + "'";` and it works fine. I am trying to avoid it because of SQL injection but not sure why the parameterized query isn't working :/ Any idea?

Comment: If you also add `@` to the name of the parameter like `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameE);` has the same effect?

Comment: Can you debug it, or setup a profiler and post the query being executed in both scenarios?

Comment: It works perfectly in VS so even if I debug it I wouldn't get any errors. But I used @Vash-DamianLeszczyński's suggestion and doing some testing and hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass invalid string for parameter.

The statement is `"SELECT * FROM [test-db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] LIKE @name"` and you pass

`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameE);`

but should

`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameE);`

PS.

You should not use `*` in SQL query you should ask only for field that you are really up to consume. As also you do not consume any of data you should use `count(*)` . Using count you should be able to gain some a performance.

Comment: Although it is true that this should be @name, I am curious as to how come the OP claims for it to "work" when run locally.

Comment: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameE);` works for me when I run my website through VS but not without it.

Comment: It should work from the server with the modification proposed by @Vash but I am still curious because it seems that without the modification, it should fail both in the server and locally.

Comment: More than errors, I would have hoped to see a difference in the final query, just so you (we) know why was it working locally even though the code was incorrect. Glad it works now for you, but I wouldn't be mad if you post both final queries :P , so we actually answer the question: why did it work in the first place?

Comment: It is strange that it was working without `@`. I have not clue what was the reason of that.

Comment: I know :/ but it's working now. Thanks for the response. I accepted and upvoted.